# How To Retrive Image from Access Database and Display it on Jlabel in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans-8

I want to retrieve image from access database and want to show it on jlabel in netbeans. I've searched a lot on Google but I couldn't find the code fo retrieving image from MS Access. Can anyone help me in this matter please? I wrote the following code but it is not working. It's giving me the error

> Record not found

```cs
DbConn obj = new DbConn();

String PatientID = getPid().getText();
String query = "Select [PatientEarImage] from PatientRecord where PatientID='"+PatientID+"'";
ResultSet rs= obj.Search(query);

try
{
    while(rs.next())
    {
        byte[] img = rs.getBytes("PatientEarImage");
        ImageIcon immgg;
        immgg = new ImageIcon();
        Image im = immgg.getImage();
        Image myImg= im.getScaledInstance(getUpload().getWidth(),  getUpload().getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        ImageIcon newImage = new ImageIcon("PatientEarImage.jpg");

        upload.setIcon(newImage);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{    
    ex.printStackTrace();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Record Found");
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working' - error message, wrong results, nothing happens? These images are stored in attachment or OLEObject field?

Comment: Sir , it is giving me error "Record Not Found" , images are stored in OLEObject field.

Comment: Does this help https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f716de15-b9f2-49a0-8ae8-624a190454de/extracting-ole-object-from-ms-access?forum=adodotnetdataproviders

Comment: i am working in Netbeans (Java) , so this might does not work in my GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Try this codes. I'm also used MS Access Database as a backend database

```
Blob filenameBlob = rs.getBlob("picture");
byte[] content = filenameBlob.getBytes(1L, (int) filenameBlob.length());
ImageIcon AA = new ImageIcon(content);
Image BB = AA.getImage();
Image CC = BB.getScaledInstance(FRAMEBOXPIC.getWidth(), FRAMEBOXPIC.getHeight(), 
java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
AA = new ImageIcon(CC);
FRAMEBOXPIC.setIcon(AA);
```